# Transparent rectangle with colored rounded corners

Tags: wpf, xaml, shapes

I'd like to set a color to the rounded corners of a rectangle in WPF.

Here's an example of what I'd like to have :

[image]

For now, I've this code :

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Transparent" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be even simpler to draw the four rounded corners as four separate Path elements:

```
<Grid>
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red"
          Data="M0,0 L10,0 A10,10 0 0 0 0,10Z"/>
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Red"
          Data="M0,0 L0,10 A10,10 0 0 0 -10,0Z"/>
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Red"
          Data="M0,0 L10,0 A10,10 0 0 1 0,-10Z"/>
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Red"
          Data="M0,0 L0,-10 A10,10 0 0 1 -10,0Z"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why should it be Rectangle? It seems that you just want to define kind of a transparent overlay with colored corners. Just use the above Grid.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="200" Width="200" >
                <Rectangle.Clip >
                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,200"/>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="transparentRect" Center="100 100" RadiusX="120" RadiusY="120"/>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    </CombinedGeometry>
                </Rectangle.Clip>
            </Rectangle>
```

**Note**

If you change the Rectangle's Size, you have to adjust the Rect and Radius-Values of the Geometries too, so it will display the proper ratio.

I did this in a few minutes, so there might be room for improvements.

Cheers

**EDIT**

For a full satisfying approach, i've made you 2 converters

**Code**

```
public class RectangleConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            var recta = value as Rectangle;
            if (recta == null) return null;
            return new Rect { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = recta.ActualHeight, Width = recta.ActualWidth };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ElipseGeoConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            var recta = value as Rectangle;
            if (recta == null) return null;
            return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(recta.ActualWidth / 2, recta.ActualHeight / 2), recta.ActualWidth / 3 * 2,
                recta.ActualHeight / 3 * 2);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" >
                <Rectangle.Clip >
                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}" Converter="{StaticResource RectangleConverter}"></Binding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}" Converter="{StaticResource GeoConverter}"/>
                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    </CombinedGeometry>
                </Rectangle.Clip>
            </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing I meant.

Comment: I can't test your code for the moment, but thank you for the answer. Seemingly, it sounds to work in light of the upvotes...  :)

Comment: How could I bind the CombinedGeometry Rect and Radius-Values to the Rectangle's ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties? My problem is that my rectangle is currently in a Grid, and its width and height are set to auto.

Comment: Either use a relative binding (in your case AncestorType = Grid) or Write a Converter for `Rect`, `Center`, `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties

Comment: @lokusking I'm sorry, but I'm new to WPF, could you please update your answer... ?  It'd be very nice!

Comment: @Drarig29 Answer updated with dynamic solution based on Converter

Comment: @lokusking Thank you very much for your work. I've learned many things (CombinedGeometry and IValueConverter) but it's a lot of stuff to implement just for 4 corners, you see... And I do like Clemens's way to do it.